I encountered a 502 Bad Gateway error on my deployed Django website
I encountered a 502 Bad Gateway error on my deployed Django website. The site was working fine until I made some modifications to enable email functionality with my website's extension. It seems that Gunicorn is not running due to a 'permission denied' error.
When I'm trying to make mails with my website extension and do reboot, my website has been disabled.
Here is the error that I encountered:
root@vps-etu:~# source /www/wwwroot/django-project/f37529200a260f346c11edf_venv/bin/activate
(51273d353f37529200a260f346c11edf_venv) root@vps-etu:~# cd /www/wwwroot/django-project
(51273d353f37529200a260f346c11edf_venv) root@vps-etu:/www/wwwroot/django-project# sudo systemctl status gunicorn
× gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon for Django project
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor pres>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-11-13 15:14:54 CET; 3h 1>
    Process: 131999 ExecStart=/www/wwwroot/django-project/f37529200a260f346>
   Main PID: 131999 (code=exited, status=3)
        CPU: 1.115s

Nov 13 15:14:52 vps-etu systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon for Djang>
Nov 13 15:14:54 vps-etu systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process ex>
Nov 13 15:14:54 vps-etu systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with res>
Nov 13 15:14:54 vps-etu systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Consumed 1.115s>
lines 1-11/11 (END)
(51273d353f37529200a260f346c11edf_venv) root@vps-etus:/www/wwwroot/django-project# sudo journalctl -u gunicorn -n 50 --no-pager
Nov 13 12:27:22 mail.etu.dz systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon for Django project.
Nov 13 12:27:22 mail.etu.dz systemd[76558]: gunicorn.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: Permission denied
Nov 13 12:27:22 mail.etu.dz systemd[76558]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /www/wwwroot/django-project/f37529200a260f346c11edf_venv/bin/gunicorn: Permission denied

Here is my gunicorn.service file:
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon for Django project
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/www/wwwroot/myproject
ExecStart=/www/wwwroot/myproject/f37529200a260f346c11edf_venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/www/wwwroot/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


Please show us your gunicorn.service file (if you've modified it)

related question

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon for Django project
After=network.target
[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/www/wwwroot/myproject
ExecStart=/www/wwwroot/myproject/f37529200a260f346c11edf_venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/www/wwwroot/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
